# Mysql won't show my databases (MYSQL-WIN7)

Tags: windows, mysql, odbc

I create a database using workbench and don't find this database at ODBC list, I'm able to see only `information_schema` database. I tried to restart my machine but don't solve the issue.

Could you help me with this?

[image]

Comment: You have installed the `MYSQL ODBC` adapter correct?  Have you verified the databases are even there?

Comment: Your output window on the bottom right shows **DROP DATABASE 'eventos'** - doesn't that command delete the database?;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find my error.

I was missing fill the user field with 'root'.
As soon I did this the connection worked :).